# Pythagorean Triples : Is every positive integer $\gt$ $2$ part of at least one Pythagorean triple?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, diophantine-equations, pythagorean-triples

I was doing some basic number theory problems from [Rosen](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321500318) and came across this problem:

> Show that every positive integer $\gt$ $2$ is part of at least one `Pythagorean triple`

**My Solution (partial)** :

*Case - 1* :

> - Let there be an integer $t$ $\ge$ 3
> - Suppose $t$ is of the form $2^{j}$ for $j > 1$
> - Let $m$ = $2^{j-1}$ and $n$ = $1$
> - So , $2mn$ = $t$ and hence $t$ belongs to a Pythagorean triple

*Case - 2 :*

> - Let $t$ = $2n + 1$
> - WLOG , let $m = n + 1$
> - Then $m$ and $n$ have opposite parity
> - Also , $m > n$
> - So , $m^{2}$ - $n^{2}$ $=$ $2n + 1$ $=$ $t$, so $t$ belongs to a Pythagorean triple

**My Problem:**

Can someone help me out ? I do not know if I am correct , I am all thumbs ; even a hint would suffice ...

Comment: THe first case should deal with $2t$, not $2^t$

Comment: You haven't checked the case when $t$ is even and not a power of $2$. Also your proof of case 2 uses redundant steps "then $m,n$ have opposite parity" and "$m>n$".

Comment: Thanks @Asvin , I got it :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using the characterisation of these triples, it suffices to show that any such number can be written as $m^2-n^2$, $2mn$ or $m^2+n^2$ with some numbers $m>n$.

The case $m^2-n^2$ covers "the most" numbers (only those $\equiv 2 \mod 4$ remain), the rest is covered by $2mn$.

Comment: Hi @MooS , could you please explain the last line of your answer in a bit detail ... would be very grateful :)

Comment: You should show that every odd number can be written as $m^2-n^2$. Any even number $2d$ greater than $2$ can be written as $2d=2 \cdot d \cdot 1$, hence is of the form $2mn$.

Comment: Hi @MooS , I have tried something out and have accordingly edited the question , please have a look and tell me if I am correct or not ... would be grateful ... :)

Comment: Note that $(m^2-n^2,2mn,m^2+n^2)$ only gives the _primitive_ triples. For example it does not give the triple $(3,0,3)$.

Comment: This is not relevant in this context. Note that those triples are only primitive if $m$ and $n$ are co-prime. Furthermore i do not think triples (n,0,n) were valid in this exercise, since that would make everything trivial.

Comment: @barto    $(m^2-n^2, 2mn,m^2+n^2)$ gives some non-primitive triples. E.g. $m=3,n=1$ gives $(6,8,10)$.... But not all triples. E.g.  not $(9,12,15)$, because there are no $m,n$ with $m^2+n^2=15$.....$ (m^2-n^2, 2mn, m^2+n^2)$ is primitive iff $m>n$ and $\gcd (m,n)=1$ and $m\not \equiv n \pmod 2.$

Answer (score 6):

> I. **Yes.** *Proof without words*:

$$(\color{brown}{2m})^2+(m^2-1)^2 = (m^2+1)^2$$

$$(\color{brown}{2m+1})^2+(2m^2+2m)^2 = (2m^2+2m+1)^2$$

> II. Higher.

To prove it for *quadruples* is easier since even and odd cases can be combined into a single identity,

$$n^2+(n+1)^2+(n^2+n)^2 = (n^2+n+1)^2$$

and for *quintuples*,

$$n^2 + (n-2)^2 + (2n+1)^2 + (3n^2+2)^2 = (3n^2+3)^2$$

Answer (score 0):

If $n$ is an odd integer, let $m = \frac{n^2 - 1}2$, then $m+1$, $m$ and $n$ are a Pythagorean triple. ($n^2 = 2m+1$)

If $n$ is even, let $m = \frac{n^2 - 4}4$, then $m+2$, $m$, and $n$ are a Pythagorean triple. $(n^2 = 4m+4)$

Comment: Please use the mathjax: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0):

If $t$ is odd and $t\geq 3$ then  $m=(t+1)/2$ and $n=(t-1)/2$ are positive integers with $m^2-n^2=t.$ And $(m^2-n^2,2mn, m^2+n^2)=(t,2mn, m^2+n^2)$ is a P. triple.

If $t$ is even and $t\geq 4$ let $m= t/2$ and $n=1$. Then $m,n$ are positive integers with $m>n$ so $(m^2-n^2,2mn,m^2+n^2)=(m^2-n^2,t,m^2+n^2)$ is a P. triple.

Answer (score 0):

For primitive triples, side $A$ can be any odd number $>2$ and side $B$ can be any integer multiple of $4$. If we include multiples like $(6,8,10)$, then the even numbers that are not multiples of $4$ are include. Therefore, every $n>2\land n\in\mathbb{N}$ is part of at least one Pythagorean triple.